# CUDA: complex scalar * double sparse matrix * double vector

Tags: c++, math, cuda

I need a function that performs operation `y = y + s*A*x` on CUDA. 
Where `y` is complex vector (`cuDoubleComplex`, for instance),  `x` is double vector, `A` is double sparse matrix (csr format) and `s` is complex scalar.

**Question**: Is there any library to perform that operation?

I would like to skip transformation everything to complex, unless you convince me that it can be done efficiently.

P.S.

Unfortunately, it can't be done by cusparse function[`cusparseCsrmvEx()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-csrmvEx)

Comment: If you're looking for a *single* library function to perform that, using the data types you specify, I don't think you'll find it.  If you are looking for a sequence of library functions, it should be possible of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any library to perform that operation?

Almost certainly not. The type promotion you need to do pretty much rules that out. What you could to is something like:

1. `cusparseDcsrmv` to yield z0 = A*x
2. custom kernel or perhaps thrust operation to yield z1 = complex(z0)
3. cublas `Zaxpy` to calculate y = y + s * z1

Even better would be to write a custom kernel to fuse (2) and (3) together. Your choice.